# Correlation structure in nlme gls

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a gls model my maximum likelihood. I want to impose the following correlation structure:

- The covariance matrix is block diagonal with three blocks of different sizes.
- The first block is diagonal with constant variance, or an identity matrix if we talk in term of correlations
- The second block is itself a block diagonal of 2 by 2 matrices. That is, the first observation is correlated with the second, the third with the forth and so on. All correlations in this block are the same, say rho1.
- The third block is like the second, but with a different correlation parameter, say rho2.

In summary, I have repeated observations within three groups. The two second group consists of paired observations which correlation I want to estimate.

I am trying to do this using the nlme package, but this is not important per se anything that works is good for me.

Any help appreciated.

Here's an example:

```
# Example data
library(MASS)
library(nlme)
e0 <- rnorm(12)
e1 <- mvrnorm(10, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.5, 0.5, 1), ncol = 2))
e2 <- mvrnorm(5, mu = c(0, 0), Sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.2, 0.2, 1), ncol = 2))

Y <- 1 + c(e0, matrix(t(e1)), matrix(t(e2)))
Pair <- factor(c(1:12, rep(13:22, each = 2), rep(23:27, each = 2)))
```

Suppose I want to estimate the mean using gls (I have a regression setting with predictors but let's simplify here) and know the true correlation structure but not the true values. If all correlations were the same, I could do (I guess)

```
gls(Y ~ 1, correlation = corCompSymm(form = ~1|Pair), method = "ML")
```

But here I want different correlation parameters for the pairs generated in e1 and those in e2. The observations in e0 are not really pairs, just iid observations.

Comment: Can you post what you've got so far?

Comment: @wogsland added an example